# pip3 install argon2-cffi-bindings errors

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

I type the following in the the command prompt: pip3 install argon2-cffi-bindings.

can anyone help me? please!

My python version is 3.6.9 and System is Debian

I received the following error:

````
```
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels
    /home/xr8022/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:119: PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning: 0.18ubuntu0.18.04.1 is an invalid version and will not be supported in a future release
      PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning,
    /home/xr8022/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py:30: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
      SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning,
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/xr8022/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 82, in fetch_build_egg
        subprocess.check_call(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 311, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmpk8kkgkyr', '--quiet', 'cffi>=1.0.1']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-_065wwx4/argon2-cffi-bindings/setup.py", line 111, in <module>
        cffi_modules=CFFI_MODULES,
      File "/home/xr8022/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 152, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "/home/xr8022/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 147, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "/home/xr8022/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 815, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/home/xr8022/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 773, in resolve
        replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting
      File "/home/xr8022/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1056, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/home/xr8022/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1068, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/home/xr8022/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 883, in fetch_build_egg
        return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
      File "/home/xr8022/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 84, in fetch_build_egg
        raise DistutilsError(str(e)) from e
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmpk8kkgkyr', '--quiet', 'cffi>=1.0.1']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-_065wwx4/argon2-cffi-bindings/
````

Comment: Have you tried installing `cffi` by itself?

Comment: you mean pip3 install cffi？

Comment: No problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try upgrading to python3.7 and `apt install libffi-dev`

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of pip do not recognize abi3 wheels and try to build from the source package. That often fails when you don't have the compiler toolchain and build dependencies installed. The simple fix is to upgrade pip so it can pick up the correct wheels. Best to update cffi and setuptools too, as the [argon2-cffi manual](https://argon2-cffi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#) says:

```
pip3 install --user -U cffi setuptools pip
```

This module does have wheels for Python 3.6 and 3.7, but you shouldn't stick to those EOL versions, because many other dependencies have dropped support.